# Unable to retrieve data from facebook graph url for a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Check out:

https://www.facebook.com/MitraJyothiorg

It is a page of an NGO.

Correspondingly, I should be able to find data of the page in:

http://graph.facebook.com/MitraJyothiorg

This does not seem to work. Any clues?

Please note: I am doing a simple http call and it usually works for other pages, for example, if i do the same thing for another page:teachforindia

Comment: What happens?  Blank page, error, what?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

You need to add at least an App Access Token. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Reading

> For pages that are published, you need:
>
> - An app or user access token is needed to view fields from fully public pages.
> - A user access token is needed to view fields from restricted pages that this person is able to view (such as those restrict to certain demographics like location or age, or those only viewable by Page admins).
> - A page access token can also be used to view those restricted fields.

Answer (score -1):

I am not able to access that page (get a `404` error). Maybe the page is still hidden? Then you will not be able to access it via the graph API imho.